# Run commands in seperate terminal using shell script (bash)

Tags: bash, unix

I want to launch several applications using "./application_name" and each in separate terminal , how do i do that in bash script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you are asking for, but this is probably what you need:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "./application_name [arguments]" &
```

This will start a new terminal emulator in the background which will be running the given command instead of a shell.

If you system does not have a `x-terminal-emulator` alias, substitute the name of an actual terminal emulator, like `xterm` or `gnome-terminal`. They (pretty much) all support the `-e` option.

Of course this requires that your bash script be running from inside an X11 session in the first place (not from a cron job or something like that), else there will be no `$DISPLAY` where the new terminal emulators can appear.

**EDIT**: Whether or not the argument to `-e` is executed under a shell or directly seems to depend on which terminal emulator is used. For example, `xterm` runs it under a shell but `gnome-terminal` doesn't. The upshot of this is that you may or may not be able to supply compound shell commands like `cd foobar; ./something & wait` as the argument to `-e`. As a workaround for those terminal emulators that *don't* run the command under a shell, you can use `-e 'sh -c "actual command"'`. Proper quoting of special characters gets [gets complicated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome) because you have two levels of quoting, but it can be done.

Comment: That's exactly what i want ,but what if i don't want to run them in background and i want the terminal to remain open .

Comment: They are running in the background: notice the `&` at the end of the command line. (If they didn't run in the background then it would wait for one to complete before starting the next, which I assumed was not what you wanted). As for your second question, the simplest way is to add `; sleep 999999999` to the end of the command (inside the quotation marks). That will just run a sleep that takes forever after the original command has exited.

Comment: One more question , how can i run two commands in a new terminal that i create using x-terminal-emulator .

Comment: You can specify any shell command line you like to the `-e` option, so it can be a one-liner that runs two commands if you like. Do you want to run two commands one after another? Then separate them with `;`. Do you want to run them simultaneously? Then use something like `-e "command1 & command2 & wait". In general, just use the same command line you would have used to launch the thing outside of a terminal.

Comment: This command seem to work when i paste it in terminal "cd ~ ;cd dir/ ; ./application" but when i do x-terminal-emulator -e "cd ~ ;cd dir/ ; ./application" & and run the bash script , it says "Failed to execute child process "cd" (No such file or directory)"

Comment: My bad. I didn't realize that some terminal emulators parse the command differently from others. See edit to the answer.

Comment: so i do this x-terminal-emulator -e 'sh -c "cd ~ ; cd dir/; ./application & wait"' & , but i don't see a new terminal and the commands .

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the full path to the command.  There are two ways depending on what you are trying to do.

terminal -e "cd ~/dir ; ./application" ; sleep 999 ;"

== or ==

terminal -e "~/dir/application ; sleep 999 ;"

The first will set the current directory before executing the commands.  The second will execute the commands without changing the current directory.  The "terminal" must be replaced with the desired terminal emulator.

i.e.:  xterm -e "~/bin/MyScript.sh ; sleep 999 ;"

The other changes are example changes as well.  Check the manpage for the terminal emulator to make sure that -e will work with it or what is needed to do the job of -e ( I do not use xterm myself ).  999 is 999 seconds.  The sleep command is set to keep the terminal window open for 999 seconds after the MyScript.sh has finished executing.

The & is missing so the terminal will run in the foreground, not the background.  As long as this is the only command executed, the trailing ; is not needed either.  In a script, the trailing ; can also be omitted if you wish to run other commands simultaneously with this command.  If the commands must be run in a specific order such that one command completes before the next command runs, then the trailing ; is required.  A command running in the background also allows other commands to be run simultaneously.  The trailing ; is not required when the command is entered into a command-line prompt.  It does help to have a space on both sides of a ; between commands ( i.e.: command ; command ).  In the examples given, the terminal should remain open while the command is running.